# Moneta (JSR354-RI) without dependency on OK-HTTP?

Tags: okhttp, java-money

I am using the JSR354 reference implementation (Moneta). It comes with a compile dependency on the OK-HTTP client – I suppose this dependency is there for the currency converter to fetch exchange rates. I do not need currency conversion, and I do not want to introduce a superfluous dependency. Is there a stripped-down version of Moneta without the converter and the dependency?